# Using a custom account for Application Pool Identity on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7.5

I am not able to change Application Pool Identity. I am using IIS 7.5 on Windows 7, 32-bit. I want to create username **jdl\UEServices**.  Here is my attachment:

[image]

Comment: does the user name exist? is that the correct password?

Comment: I am not able to create username jdl/UEServices.

Comment: You have to create the user in Active Directory first.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create accounts in IIS. In IIS you configure the process to run under an existing account.

Therefore, the account must be created in Active Directory or in the control panel under accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Under Computer Management on Windows, you will be able to create a local user. In that way you can give "life" to your user. Just remembering this is a workaround, in casee you are not under a domain thus making the user being acceptable as a custom app pool identity on IIS avoid the pool being stopped once a request raised. The local user and custom user on IIS must have the same username and password entries.